# Spectrogram of sound pressure data

Tags: frequency-spectrum

I have sound pressure data in the form of Pascal,Pascal A-weighted, dB, and dBA. I want to compute a spectrogram in MATLAB.And I want to show color values as sound pressure level (dBA).But when I am computing the spectrogram the values are higher even higher than the maximum possible values. Can anyone please let me know what I'm doing wrong and what would be the right way to show SPL (dBA) values. Here is the code I am using:

```
% Parameters for the spectrogram 
window_length = hamming(512);   % Hamming window of length 256
noverlap = 256;          % 50% overlap between segments
nfft = 1024;              % Number of points in FFT
% Compute the spectrogram 
[S, F, T, P] = spectrogram(driveby_A_weighted, window_length, noverlap, nfft, samplerate);
% Display the spectrogram 
figure;
imagesc(T, F, 20 * log10(abs(S) / 20e-6));  % Convert to dB scale
axis xy;  % Flip the y-axis to have lower frequencies at the bottom
xlabel('Time (s)', 'FontSize', 15, 'FontWeight', 'bold'); % Adjust x-axis label font properties
ylabel('Frequency (Hz)', 'FontSize', 15, 'FontWeight', 'bold'); % Adjust y-axis label font properties
title('Spectrogram', 'FontSize', 15, 'FontWeight', 'bold'); % Adjust title font properties
colorbar;  % Display the colorbar showing the power levels
ylabel(colorbar, 'Sound Pressure Level (dbA)', 'FontSize', 15, 'FontWeight', 'bold'); % Adjust colorbar label font properties
% Adjusting Y-axis ticks with a step of 0.1*10^4 Hz
desired_y_ticks = 0:0.1*10^4:max(F);  % Define the desired range of Y-axis ticks
yticks(desired_y_ticks);         % Set the Y-axis ticks
set(gca, 'FontSize', 15); % Adjust font size for axis ticks
```

Comment: Why are you dividing the spectrogram by $20e^{-6}$?? Doing that, you’re scaling the result by a factor of $20’000’000!$

Comment: $20\mu Pa$ is the reference pressure for dBSPL

Comment: @Shivam: are you sure your data is properly calibrated and in actual Pa? If yes, what are the amplitude ranges of your data ?

Comment: @Hilmar oh duh…